# Run command in background and capture result later (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency

Similar to these questions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250507/fork-command-in-background-using-ampersand-when-bash-scripting-and-capture-o), I'm wanting to run a command in a  background process, carry on processing, then later use the return value from that command.

I have one function in my script that takes particularly long, so I would like to run it first before the rest of the setup so that there is less of a delay when the return value of that script is given, but currently the return value doesn't get captured.

What I've tried:

```
if [ $LAZY_LOAD -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "INFO - Getting least loaded server in background. Can take up to 30s."
    local leastLoaded=$( getLeastLoaded ) &
fi

# Other setup stuff that doesn't use leastLoaded...
# setup setup setup....

if [ $LAZY_LOAD -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "INFO - Waiting for least loaded server to be retrieved before continuing"
    wait

fi

echo "INFO - Doing stuff with $leastLoaded."
doThingWithLeastLoaded $leastLoaded
```

getLeastLoaded definitely works without the &, so I'm sure this is a concurrency issue.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot set a variable from a background job. Write the result to a temporary file or fifo. If you have a lot of jobs you want to execute in parallel, consider using `make` or GNU `parallel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to bash [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command in the background **in a subshell**.

So your `local` command would not affect the current shell.

I'd suggest like this:

```
do-something > /some/file &
... ...
wait
var=$( cat /some/file )
```